# Multer gridfs Storage

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, multer, multer-gridfs-storage

I wanted to change my filename but when I examine console.log (`req.file`) I can see the filename I changed to, but a different filename is saved in the database using `Multergridfs Storage`.

```js
 1. the default filename 
 const storage = new GridFsStorage({
    url: config.db,
    file: (req, file) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
                if (err) {
                    return reject(err)
                }
                const filename = 'file' + path.extname(file.originalname);
                const fileInfo = {
                    filename: filename,
                    bucketName: 'contents'
                };
                resolve(fileInfo);
            });
        });
    }});

2 this is where i edited the filename

router.post('/', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    req.file.filename = req.body.fileName + path.extname(req.file.originalname)
    res.redirect('/upload/files')
    
    console.log(req.file)
});
```

the result of the console is something like

> { fieldname: 'file',
>     originalname: '\'YOU CAN ALSO BE GREAT\' -  Elon Musk Motivation  -  Motivational Video.mp4',
>     encoding: '7bit',
>     mimetype: 'video/mp4',
>     id: 5bfb292c13eec142f6c20fd9,
>     filename: 'a.mp4',
>     metadata: null,
>     bucketName: 'contents',
>     chunkSize: 261120,
>     size: 19372377,
>     md5: '513c6220ef3afff644cf8a6dc4cd9130',
>     uploadDate: 2018-11-25T22:58:52.625Z,
>     contentType: 'video/mp4' }
>   { fileName: 'a' }

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please copy and paste any code you want to display into the question. Best not to use embedded images for code or error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part in your code

```
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
    url: config.db,
    file: (req, file) => { // In this function is where you configure the name of your file
```

The `file` configuration is the one that computes the filename before inserting the file in the database. What you are doing is:

1. Generating a name like `'file'` plus whatever extension comes from the browser, eg: `'file.mp4'`
2. Saving a file with that name into the database
3. Overwriting a property in your request with a new name
4. The file in the database remains unchanged

I think what you really wanted was to generate the correct name **before inserting**

You can do this by using

```
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
    url: config.db,
    file: (req, file) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            crypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
                if (err) {
                    return reject(err)
                }
                // In here you have access to the request and also to the body object
                const filename = req.body.fileName + path.extname(file.originalname);
                const fileInfo = {
                    filename: filename,
                    bucketName: 'contents'
                };
                resolve(fileInfo);
            });
        });
    }});
```

Make sure you send all the fields before the file from the form in your browser or some values will be `undefined` because they are not processed yet.

Comment: The `file` object or `files` array are plain javascript objects. You can set new properties directly on them. Does this solution works for you?

Comment: @SadiqMustaphaAji Alternatively you can create your own objects from them and manipulate those directly

Comment: Please can you provide example on how to create the object. @devconcept

Comment: @SadiqMustaphaAji One thing first, are you aware that changing those properties has no effect on your database structure. Did you intend to persist those fields in the database?

Comment: Yes @devconcept

Comment: i wish to continue adding the fields ?

Comment: @SadiqMustaphaAji There are two ways for this, one you save the fields on a regular table adding an id field to reference your file id or you store them on the metadata of the file. I'll always prefer the first way because data is easily accessible. You can get your file using the standard `GridFSBucket` and mongodb

Comment: Please can you provide example in code for the first method i have tried the metadata method but i'm not satisfied with

Comment: If you don't mind also please drop your social media handle so i could reach out for you @devconcept

Comment: @SadiqMustaphaAji What you want is a completely different question. Show some effort and try to implement your example first and then create a new question in StackOverflow. You'll get a lot of answers and learn in the process. Asking for a private instructor is a little bit extreme, don't you think?

Comment: I have check and asked alot that's why i'm asking you sorry if its overwhelming on you

Comment: @SadiqMustaphaAji Create a new question showing what you have so far and write me a comment with the link. I will happily give you a hand.

Comment: check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53548990/how-do-i-add-new-field-other-than-multer-gridfs-storage-default-properties