# How do i add new field other than multer-gridfs-storage default properties

Tags: node.js, express, multer, multer-gridfs-storage

I wanted to add new fields (objects) other than multer-gridfs-storage default fields but to no avail, the fields I want to add are:

- Description
- category
- Token

The default field has something like

- _id
- length
- chunksize
- uploadDate
- md5
- contentType

instead, want to add something like

- _id
- length
- chunksize
- uploadDate
- md5
- contentType
- description
- category and the rest

And also is there a way to add a thumbnail to file so I don't I have reference my file id to the thumbnail in another collection

```
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
    url: config.db,
    file: (req, file) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        
                const filename = req.body.fileName + path.extname(file.originalname);
                const Description = req.body.Description
                const fileInfo = {
                    filename: filename,
                    bucketName: 'contents',
                    metadata: req.body,
                    
                }
                resolve(fileInfo, Description);
            
        });
    }
});
const   upload = multer({
    storage
});
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
    console.log(req.body)
});

//** uploading file to the db */

router.post('/', upload.any(), (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('/upload/files')
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those properties are populated by [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#file-information) and further enhanced by whatever storage engine you are using, in this case [multer-gridfs-storage](https://github.com/devconcept/multer-gridfs-storage#file-information) when the file is stored. You won't be able to manipulate those yourself because they are generated when the file is parsed in the request and then when it is stored in the database.

Instead of using metadata to store your business logic you should use a framework like [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/) and store that information on a collection and use an id field to get a link to your file. Something like this

```
const Movie = mongoose.model('Movie', { 
    description: String,
    category: String,
    token: String,
    fileId: Schema.Types.ObjectId
});
```

Read your fields from the body and save them using this collection to the database and use the autogenerated `_id` of your file as the `fileId`. This way you can easily query your data and still have a handle to the file available.

Comment: The above method you propose doesn't is generating some id other than the file id

Comment: I created new schema named movie reference the id as you told me to

Comment: checkout these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53558684/multer-gridfs-storage-referencing-uploaded-file-to-a-new-collection @devconcept