# Cannot get file inside req.file using multer-gridfs-storage

Tags: node.js, file-upload, mern, multer, multer-gridfs-storage

I am trying to upload an image and have it saved inside mongodb. But I am not getting the file inside req.file object.

This is my API file:

```
import axios from 'axios';

import { API_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE, SERVICE_URLS } from '../constants/config';

const API_URL = 'http://localhost:4000'

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: API_URL,
    timeout: 10000,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
})

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
    function (config) {
        return config
    },
    function (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    function (response) {
        return processResponse(response);
    },
    function (error) {
        return Promise.reject(processError(error));
    }
);

const processResponse = (response) => {
    if (response?.status === 200) {
        return { isSuccess: true, data: response?.data }
    } else {
        return {
            isFailure: true,
            status: response?.status,
            msg: response?.msg,
            code: response?.code
        }
    }
}

const processError = (error) => {
    if (error.response) {
        console.log('Error in response: ', error);
        return {
            isError: true,
            msg: API_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE.responseFailure,
            code: error.response.status
        };
    } else if (error.request) {
        console.log('Error in request: ', error);
        return {
            isError: true,
            msg: API_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE.requestFailure,
            code: ""
        };
    } else {
        console.log('Error in network: ', error);
        return {
            isError: true,
            msg: API_NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE.networkError,
            code: ""
        };
    }
}

const API = {};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(SERVICE_URLS)) {
    API[key] = (body, showUploadProgress, showDownloadProgress) =>
        axiosInstance({
            method: value.method,
            url: value.url,
            data: body,
            responseType: value.responseType,
            onUploadProgress: function (progressEvent) {
                if (showUploadProgress) {
                    let percentageCompleted = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total);
                    showUploadProgress(percentageCompleted);
                }
            },
            onDownlaodProgress: function (progressEvent) {
                if (showDownloadProgress) {
                    let percentageCompleted = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total);
                    showDownloadProgress(percentageCompleted);
                }
            }
        })
}

export { API };
```

Here is my react app useEffect code:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const getImage = async () => {
            if(file) {
                const data = new FormData();
                data.append('name', file.name);
                data.append('file', file)

                // API call for uploading image
                for (var key of data.entries()) {
                    console.log(key[0] + ', ' + key[1]);
                }
                const response = await API.uploadFile(data);
                console.log('response:', response);
                // get a url
                post.picture = response.data // TODO
            }
        }
        getImage();
        post.categories = location.search?.split('=')[1] || 'All';
        post.username = account.username;
    }, [file]);
```

The console.log for the data prints this:

```
name, demo-img-1.jpg
file, [object file]
```

And this is my server-side middleware:

```
import multer from 'multer';
import { GridFsStorage } from 'multer-gridfs-storage';

import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

const storage = new GridFsStorage({
    url : process.env.DB_URI,
    file: (req, file) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if(['image/png', 'image/jpg'].indexOf(file.mimetype) === -1) {
                resolve(`${Date.now()}-blog-${file.originalName}`);
            }

            resolve({
                bucketName: 'photos',
                filename: `${Date.now()}-blog-${file.originalName}`
            });
        })
    }
});

export default multer({ storage });
```

This is my route:

```
router.post('/file/upload', upload.single('file'), uploadImage);
```

And this is my controller:

```
export const uploadImage = (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('req.file: ', req.file);
    console.log('==========================================');
    console.log('req.body: ', req.body);
    console.log('==========================================');
    if(!req.file){
        return res.status(400).json('No file uploaded');
    }

    res.status(200).json(req.file.filename);
}
```

These console prints this:

```
req.file:  undefined
==========================================
req.body:  { name: 'demo-img-1.jpg', file: {} }
==========================================
```

Now I have tried several things, even tried to use only the multer instead of multer-gridfs-storage but I got the same result. Where do you think this is going wrong.?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to share the code for `API.uploadFile()`. I suspect you're manually setting the content-type header to an incorrect value (a common mistake)

Comment: There doesn't seem any reason for your GridFsStorage `file` function to return a promise. Why are you doing that?

Comment: I was reading this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53558684/multer-gridfs-storage-referencing-uploaded-file-to-a-new-collection) answer and took it from there. Before it was normal return statements instead of resolve()

I edited the question to include the API file too.

Comment: Thanks for the update. First, remove the default `headers` from your Axios instance, they are completely unnecessary. Second, can you try switching out the Multer storage with `multer.memoryStorage()` just to rule out if `GridFsStorage` is a problem or not. And finally, check your browser's dev-tools _Network_ panel to inspect the request just to make sure a `file` field is being sent

Comment: multer.memoryStorage() does work! it gives me the req.file and yes, the request does send file field

Comment: Great, that means you can rule out any client-side issues. Time to do more debugging. Make sure `process.env.DB_URI` is set correctly and perhaps try without `file` to use the [defaults](https://github.com/devconcept/multer-gridfs-storage#file)